# OC document with mixed mathematics and text

Tags: script, automation, ocr, scanning, tesseract-ocr

I have a document containing math-equations that I want to translate to another language using google translate. What I would have done if it was a text-document with images, is to use any ocr-software and copy-pasted the text into google translate and just ignored the images. This document is different because:

- The equations are partially text, so they might be partially recognized by OCR, but the meaning of the article changes if the equations are not reproduced exactly as they are (say simply changing a sub-script to a super-script changes the meaning).
- There are several hundreds pieces of mathematics, so the process of dealing with the mathematics has to be reliable (in some sense).

So my idea was to try to make a script that would ocr the text. While for the equations, find some way to automate the conversion of those into images, and automate the insertion of those images in-between the strings after they had been translated by google translate. It was quick to use a highlighter-pen to mask the maths out from the text (see below). I imagine I could use the yellow mask with a terminal-graphics program to select the masked areas and automate the separation of those areas into small individual images.

My question then is either one of:

1. Does there exist software that can do the entire process without having to write any code myself? If not:
2. How can I extract every string from the text, and automate the book-keeping of which string comes before which image? That way they can be put back together again after the OCR+translation.

[image: An article containing equations]

Comment: There are some sites claiming OCR for mathematical formulae, e.g., https://mathpix.com/ocr, https://www.i2ocr.com/free-online-math-equation-ocr, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145048/is-there-an-ocr-that-can-convert-an-image-of-a-formula-into-a-tex-markup . Perhaps a (neutron) moderator can suggest something? Or take a quantum leap and try the StackUser Tex site, displacing the question there if you don't get an answer here.